# GCP: Directing traffic from Global HTTP Load Balancer to istio internal load balancer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, istio

I have GKE clusters in 2 regions on a shared VPC network, both are running istio and I need to globally load balance between them. Having set up each cluster with an istio-ilbgateway with port 80 exposed, a GCP internal regional load balancer is created and assigned an external IP on the region’s subnet. I can see  corresponding backend services for both ilb-gateways. However, when setting up a Global HTTP Load Balancer with the new backend services and pinging the global load balancer’s IP, requests are directed by it to the IP address of one of the cluster’s nodes NOT to the ip address of an internal load balancer as I expected.

Is what I am trying to achieve here possible? If so, is there a step missing above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set up a Global Loadbalancer on top of Istio. However, you can't reach the TCP load balancer automatically set up by Istio Ingress Gateway.

This Ingress Gateway, is a K8S service which expose NodePorts. You can get them with this commands:

```
# For HTTP
kubectl -n istio-system get service istio-ingressgateway -o jsonpath='{.spec.ports[?(@.name=="http2")].nodePort}'

# For HTTPS
kubectl -n istio-system get service istio-ingressgateway -o jsonpath='{.spec.ports[?(@.name=="https")].nodePort}'
```

Now you can set up your Global Load balancer backend with the Instance Group created by your cluster and the NodePort. By This way, your traffic will be route to Istio without using the Ingress gateway (-> the TCP Loadbalancer).

About the 2 regions, you should have 2 instances groups, 1 in each region, and 2 TCP Load Balancer, 1 in each region. By the way, you can define 2 different backends on your Global Load Balancer, but your can't loadbalance the same traffic between the 2 regions. You will have 2 different path-rules, thus 2 different URL entries

**UPDATE**

After reflection, if you want to route the same traffic in the 2 regions, you have to rely on Dynamic DNS service which perform this kind of loadbalancing. Most of time, this kind of DNS service include an Health Check to verify if your region is responding or not. Today Google Global Load Balancing don't allow this. I know that Cloudflare do this.

Comment: I'm using GKE, can I direct traffic from global http load balancer to nginx ingress controller?

Comment: The global load balancer does not require dynamic DNS because the external IP address of the GCLB uses anycast. If the two groups are added to the same backend service then the load balancer will go between them based on the balancing specified in that backend service. Configured this way the global load balancer will also route traffic to the region closest to the user if they are not overloaded.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to achieve is not possible. For 2 reasons.

1. GCP does not have GKE Ingress that can handle two different clusters. This is called multi cluster ingress and is not supported.
2. GCP load balancer can not have another load balancer as a backend.

Comment: Thanks, @EliasH. For clarity, is there a recommended approach to resolve point 2 above? I can successfully ping the istio-ilbgateway from VMs on the same subnet. Is it correct that if the global load balancer directs traffic to a VM not running istio or using any other type of Ingress, that VM can then utilise the internal load balancer of a cluster in its subnet?

Comment: On August 14th, we received an email from GCP regarding an envoy vulnerability requiring a patch - the interim fix purports to be an HTTP Load Balancer in front of the istio ingress gateway: 

“The new versions of GKE (1.12.9-gke.15, 1.13.7-gke.24) will begin rolling out between August 19 and August 22, 2019. You can follow the status of those rollouts on the GKE Release Notes page.
In the meantime, you can mitigate the HTTP/2 vulnerability by using an HTTP(S) Load Balancer in front of your Istio Ingress”
How is that achieved? The istio ingress gateway is not a backend service either.

Answer (score 0):

GCP has a separate tool for you to use to set up a global ingress called KubeMCI it requires a bit of manual intervention, for example, the service your routing to in this case your Istio gateway needs to be running as node port instead of load balancer and the node port needs to be exactly the same on every cluster where you want it to respond to.

The how-to makes no reference to Istio just Kubernetes services and I don't think TCP is available yet just HTTP(s). Bare in mind it specifically says that kubemci is a temporary tool until they build the functionality into Kubectl.

But providing you configure the node ports the same it should work well.

Here is the official documentation:
https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/multi-cluster-ingress